# How can this formula be analyzed intuitively?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vibrations

Given

$$
\bar{U}_{vib}(T) = R \sum_{\text{n.m.}} \left( \frac{\theta_{vib, n.m.}}{2} \right) + \frac{\theta_{vib, n.m.} e^{-\theta_{vib, n.m.}/T}}{1-e^{-\theta_{vib, n.m.}/T}}
$$

where $\bar{U}_{vib}$ is the molar vibrational energy of a polyatomic molecule, n.m. refers to "normal modes" $\in \{1,2,3\}$ and $\theta_{vib,1}=2290$, $\theta_{vib, 2} = 5160$ and $\theta_{vib, 3}=5360$, all in $K$.

Which component of the sum will have the lowest value at $T=3000K$?

Can one see that directly somehow by a smart analysis or will I specifically need to compute the various terms of the sum?

Comment: Well you only have three numbers to compute, and none of these are particularly difficult. If you absolutely must do something fancier then note you can rewrite this as $U = RT\sum_{n.m.} x_{n.m.} \mathrm{coth}(x_{n.m.})$ for some $x_{n.m.}$ which you'll have to work out, and $x \mathrm{coth} x$ is a [monotonic function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+coth[x]+for+x+%3D+0+to+10). You might want to think of a physical reason for a particular mode to be the lowest.

Comment: Sure, brute forcing it is feasible. But say I had 20 terms, would it still be possible? I just thought, maybe I'm missing something obvious.